# Was my skepsis justified?

Tags: limits, graphing-functions, learning

The other day I got asked to answer a survey, in order to get to know, why people sometimes have problems learning limits. I got asked some, in my humble opinion, rather easy questions for a math student having taken courses on the subject.

You got presented with a picture and in some cases the also an explicit function, and I got asked whether it converged, diverged or I didn't know.

Here is an example [image: Example 1]

In this case, you got asked the limit as x -> 0. You didn't have to prove anything nor give the relevant limit, just answer whether or not it existed.

Turning to the last question, I got the following question 
[image: Example 2]

Here I got asked in the limit as $ x \rightarrow \infty$.

I had two difficulties with the question.
1. I didn't which rate, that the wave function was decaying with and 
2. I didn't know, if it was increasing og decreasing with a slow rate.

This turned me two answer "I don't know" as I didn't think it could be determined with this plot alone. The answer was unfortunately that it converged.

So my two questions is:
Was my skepsis justified and do you know what function is plotted in the second example?

Comment: This is not really about math, but about what is "reasonable" to expect from such a problem. It's like when shown the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\ldots$ and asked what is the next term. The "reasonable" answer is $10$, but it's easy to construct a sequence such that this is not the case. Btw as a sidenote, how can a "I don't know" answer ever be wrong?! If you don't know it's correct:)

Comment: @Winther I sorta disagree. Note that my question was two sided. First what function is pictured, and two is my skepsis reasonable. By reasonable I mean, is it possible to construct a function, that have same properties as the one pictured, but don't converge. I don't find it not math related asking other people, what level of skepsis they would apply to a math question.

Comment: The function could be something like $1 - \frac{\sin(x/10)}{x/10}$. Of course it's possible to construct such a function that diverges just as it's possible to construct a sequence where the next term is $42$ instead of $10$ (e.g. add $10^{-10}\cdot e^x$ to the function above). For such a test then I don't think your skepsis is reasonable. It would be a trick question if shown that function and the true answer was that it didn't converge and I would not expect a trick question on such a test.

Comment: I think one can fairly assume, that the behaviour seen in the graph will continue. My question is just, is that enough to conclude it converges. I mean, looking at the $ \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i} $ could look like it converges, but could the same principle be true for decays wave functions?

Comment: Ok I thought you were asking if you were "technical correct" or something like that. But then I don't understand your problem. You are asked to interpret a picture showing a trend. The trend is clearly that the function gets closer and closer to $1$. Informally getting closer and closer to something is what convergence to a limit is.